# MVC making a global js variable for partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Ok, here is the scenario. I have a partial view in mvc app that is being rendered as a kendo popup window content. Now, I need to create a variable (which is array) that I can access from any method inside this partial view script, but it should be invisible from out of this popup. Reason is that I need to store data for this specific popup in it, and there can be several such popups. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you really want a private variable for a popup or you just want a unique variable for each popup?

Comment: @rajeemcariazo, unique variable for each popup. Sorry if I was not clear enough, my English is far from perfect

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your window, you can set a variable for that like this:

```
var myWindow = $("#window");
myWindow[0].myVariable = [1,2,3];
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, to get better answers you should try to make your question as generic as possible. Assuming knowledge of Kendo, means that only those familiar with Kendo can answer (at least easily), whereas this is really inspecific to fact that you're using Kendo. Better would be to say "I have a modal window that displays HTML rendered on the same page (i.e. not through an iframe or something)."

Anyways, you'll simply want to use some sort of array or object to hold all the variables for the popups. You should absolutely not rely on the JavaScript `window` object, as anything stored there is truly global and could be overwritten or otherwise tampered with by any number of other scripts running on the page. You should create a namespace for your application, if you have not done so already, and store anything and everything in that namespace:

```
var MyAwesomeNamespace = MyAwesomeNamespace || {};

MyAwesomeNamespace.foo = "bar";
```

The name doesn't matter; just pick something unique that's unlikely to be used by anyone else in the world, like perhaps the name of your organization.

Once you have this, then like I said, you'll want to use an array or an object. Which you choose depends on how you want to handle it. With an array, you'll need to pick out values via some integer index. If your popups are rendered via a for loop, for example, you could assign them an id or data-* attribute that contains this index and then use that to pick the right item from the array.

If things are little more random than that, you'll probably just want to use an object and key by some property on the popup like its id:

```
MyAwesomeNamespace.PopupVariables[popup.getAttribute(id)];
```